# How do I get rid of this compile Error in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_CmdImportExcel_Click

Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport,acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml,[Consumables Inventory List],[C:\jmoree_import\Consumables Project],True)

Exit_CmdImportExcel_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Command13_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume Exit_Command13_Click
End Sub
```

"I keep getting a Compile Error Any help would be great"

Comment: Wrap your strings with `"` double quotes.

Comment: To clarify, “[“ and “]” are quotes in Access SQL, but *not* in Access VBA.  You’ll need to change them to quotation marks (“...”) in VBA.

Comment: This was meant to be a bit of code that is attached to a button that will pull a sheet from a file and append a table in the database. The brackets were a product of the drop-down example provided by VBA as I was typing it in.  I tried replacing them with quotes and it gave me the same error.

Comment: It says there is a Syntax error. I must being doing something wrong in addition to the quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few issues:

1. You need to surround literal string arguments with double-quotes, e.g.:

   ```
   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Consumables Inventory List", "C:\jmoree_import\Consumables Project", True
   ' Missing double-quotes -----------------------------------------^--------------------------^--^------------------------------------^
   ```
2. You have a trailing closing parenthesis:

   ```
   Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, ..., True)
   ' Trailing closing parenthesis should not be here ------------------------^
   ```
3. You need to specify the full filename of an `.xls/.xlsx` file to be imported, not just a filepath:

   ```
   "C:\jmoree_import\Consumables Project"
   ```

   This should be something like:

   ```
   "C:\jmoree_import\Consumables Project\Consumables.xlsx"
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much. You guys have been very helpful